# Retrieve static html content from client cache (dynamic content)

Tags: php, caching

I was developing a website on a certain web host and they lost everything. They told me their disks crashed and even the backup are unretrievable. I am mad.

As I was often accessing my website through my personal browser, is there any way I can get the static html content from my cache for my webpages?

I managed to find the css, pictures and js files from my local cache, but I would really want to also get back all the html and texts (content) that I've written.

The webpages were generated dynamically (php) from a database (mysql) so I found no html files containing the text for each of my pages.

Is there a way I can get these texts or any trace of html source for my webpages..?

Thanks in advance...

## Conclusion : Avoid MyResellerHome web hosting at all cost.

Comment: Who was the host? ... so others can avoid them

Comment: maybe google cached your pages?

Comment: The host was MyResellerHome. Please anyone, do yourself a favor and if you need web hosting, avoid them at all cost as the quality of their service is abysmal, from customer service to hardware used.

Comment: @Vytautas : Good idea, unfortunately I don't think so :( It was not publicly ready yet and I tried to avoid being indexed by Google for now...I will still check, maybe Google is wiser than me. edit : no luck...

Comment: in firefox you can enable offline mode and try to access your page maybe you will find any hope :D

Comment: If I go to about:cache in Firefox, I get 0 entries for the Offline Cache...I am not sure how this mode works. I have some entries in the standard Disk cache, where I found some files (js, css, pics) but no html or content files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not, I'm afraid is the short answer.

Looking through my IE cache, there are hardly any HTML documents or similar. There are a few files with a `.php` extension which contain the HTML that was generated by the execution of those PHP scripts, but not many - probably not nearly enough for your purposes.

My Firefox cache has absolutely nothing like this - it is all images, css and js.

Slightly embarrasingly, I can't find my Chrome cache on my hard drive...